Problem transfering ERC 20 tokens to another adress
I've been trying to transfer some ERC-20 tokens to my master address, but I always receive the same error: "The Safe SDK could not be initialized. Please be aware that we only support v1.0.0 Safe Accounts and up."
I've tried everything: changing RPC, changing browser, exploring tutorials, and talking with customer service. They told me I need to use the Safe CLI, but I'm not a developer and can't find any real step-by-step tutorial on using CLI to send a transaction. Could you please help me?

Can you give more information on your safe (version, networks, etc.) as well as the code you used to initialize the safe?
For step-by-step info on how to use the CLI, you can also refer to my answer in this question: ETH address under OP Network
Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Hi Louis! I use web version with polygon with this safe wallet address: matic:0x89d09e1a956c62B6e88C87D2d2cA2866d478235e
I start the safe wallet in the desktop web and I receive this message: This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. It should ONLY be used for fund recovery.
Id been trying following your instructions with this code:
safe-cli 0x89d09e1a956c62B6e88C87D2d2cA2866d478235e https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/MYAPIKEY
But I can't progress because I receive:
No such command '0x89d09e1a956c62b6e88c87d2d2ca2866d478235e'.

It acts like the safe-cli was not correctly installed on your machine. Was the installation of the Safe CLI successful?
